# How to test my camera app on many different devices

Tags: android, testing, camera

There are lots of app cloud testing solutions out there, but I didn't find anyone supporting native camera testing (runtime errors, focusing, aspect ratio of preview and taken images). Camera hardware is quite dependent on devices and implementation of the API is still far from simple, which introduces a big potential for device dependant bugs.
Can anyone recommend a service or a tool for testing on several hardware devices at once?

Comment: Hi my friend please read [ask], your question is "primarily opinion-based":
Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Ok, I changed the title. The answers will still be opinion based- you are right. But I would still care. I am looking for a tool to test my camera app on many devices, and I can't find any. I also don't know how to rephrase my question, since it's representing my issue very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out [Kobiton](https://kobiton.com/freetrial/). I have only use it for a couples of time but it connect to a physical devices remotely for you to test your apps. For that, it is limited in devices (it still have more then 18 devices for android though).

Answer (score 1):

You can use firebase test lab Physical testing option you can get details from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/). You can even Test on Physical Devices. its supported by google